# Computing gene frequency of specific domain regions using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, methods, bioinformatics, density-plot

I'm studying genome topology in plants in order to understand the organisation/compartimentalization of the nuclear genome.

I wanted to know a quick methods to compute gene density over specific genome regions of interest in order to plot the gene frequencies per comp per bin +/- 50Kb from the start and the end of the region.

Has someone any idea to resolve this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to get up to speed with Bioconductor packages such as ```GenomicFeatures``` ```GenomicRanges``` and ```Biostrings```. I hope you know that there isn't a one step solution for what you're looking for.. Try looking through vignettes of the above packages and what's already been done by others.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I try to used GenomicRanges and GenomicFeatures, using the function "GenomicRanges::slidingWindows()" for exemple. The fact is that I cannot binarized my region of interest at the same number of bins for normalisation.

Comment: I would also recommend you post your bioinformatics queries on Biostars group. Most of what I learnt comes from discussions there. Including queries such as yours.

Comment: Yes you right, I will do it now. Thanks.

Comment: what is gene density? if you errm give an example of say data.frame of gene and data.frame of regions..  it would be easier to help

Comment: Sorry I will post now all the informations

Comment: I've post all the information sin other Answer section

Answer (score 0):

If you want I've post in Biostar with more information of that I do :

[post in BioStar with figures exemple of the wanted output](https://www.biostars.org/p/436172/)

So For gene density, I mean the number of gene that are overlapped my regions. But I've to normalized this count with my region size because they have not the same size.

here you have my region dataframe object :

```
> head(regionFileCustom)
            chr startCust  endCust                     id score strand
1 CMiso1.1chr01    -50000  3550000  Domain-1CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
2 CMiso1.1chr01  14450000 15300000 Domain-17CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
3 CMiso1.1chr01  15250000 15500000 Domain-18CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
4 CMiso1.1chr01  15600000 16650000 Domain-19CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
5 CMiso1.1chr01  16600000 17050000 Domain-20CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
6 CMiso1.1chr01  26950000 27450000 Domain-34CMiso1.1chr01  1000      +
```

then my gene dataframe object :

```
> head(features)
            chr start   end                    id score strand
1 CMiso1.1chr01   955 24594 CMiso1.1chr01g0058061     .      +
2 CMiso1.1chr01 24595 25591 CMiso1.1chr01g0058071     .      -
3 CMiso1.1chr01 25797 30580 CMiso1.1chr01g0058081     .      +
4 CMiso1.1chr01 31006 35465 CMiso1.1chr01g0058091     .      -
5 CMiso1.1chr01 41322 41398 CMiso1.1chr01g0058101     .      -
6 CMiso1.1chr01 42694 46218 CMiso1.1chr01g0058111     .      -
```

So to do the count I ve try this own build function :

```
# function to compute the gene density per bin and the gene frequency (gene per bin per nbr of bin per genome region)

width = 201L
step=201L
n = 100
minoverlap=21L
maxgap=-1L
ignore.strand=TRUE # I don't know yet if I have to take in count the strand for this part of the analysis.

# For test windowBin.gr = windowBinVarName

computeFeatureFreq <- function(features, regionFile, outDFName){
  # convert feature as GRange
  features.gr = makeGRangesFromDataFrame(features)
  # convert regionFile as Grange
  regionFile.gr = makeGRangesFromDataFrame(regionFile)
  # Counting gene density per genome region
  # feature.density.windowBin = countOverlaps(windowBin.gr,features.gr,ignore.strand=ignore.strand, minoverlap=minoverlap, maxgap=maxgap)
  # feature.density.windowBin = countOverlaps(features.gr, windowBin.gr,ignore.strand=ignore.strand, minoverlap=minoverlap, maxgap=maxgap)
  feature.density.region = countOverlaps(features.gr, regionFile.gr)
  # retreive coordonates for each windowBin
  regionFile.df=as.data.frame(regionFile.gr)
  feature.density.region.df = data.frame(chr=regionFile.df$seqnames, start=regionFile.df$start, end=regionFile.df$end, count=feature.density.region)
  return(feature.density.region.df)
}
```

If somethings is not clear tell me, thanks